# How do I change master page for a specific applicaiton page in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I created  custom access denied page through OOB. Now i would like to change the master page. Can anyone explain how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Application page for the same, as you need to apply different Master Page for particular Page and also Page should be visible to person who does not have permission for the particular item or page....

You can also inherit the Master page and layout from the exiting access denied page and customize as per your requirement..

Below links may help you solve your problem:

Create Custom access denied Page: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31253.sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-custom-access-denied-page.aspx

How to set Custom Access Denied Page:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5c40d604-bdb4-405a-88d6-a0d3b4eb0af1/how-to-set-custom-access-denied-pages-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment